# Datagridview cell with listbox

Tags: vb.net

how to host listbox control in a datagridview? I am currently creating a custom control in datagridview and I want that whenever I click on the cell a listbox with suggestion and multicolumn. This is like a textbox with autocomplete.

This control is what I'm looking for. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvaU-aNoI5Y

Comment: listbox inside datagridview cell.. are you sure? why not combobox? you can have suggestions and dropdown list for the user to choose from.

Comment: Hi Sir, im looking for a control similar to this one. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvaU-aNoI5Y

Comment: ok...now i understand it looks like another datagridview and not a listbox, its looks like its custom made. you can achive something similar if you create a custom form with another datagridview, then in every cell click event you will create an instance of this form and pass the requested information to show to the instance. thats the general idea..